# Using jQuery Ajax with node.js and express to validate sending an email

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, contact-form

So, I have this contact form in the website I'm making, I'm using a template I found online that uses ajax to validate that the form is working and the email has been sent, the problem is that this file that validates the form is set to work with PHP I think, so I tried modifying the file that has ajax to make it work with my node app, but I end up with the form loading forever and I get Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in the console.

note: the form is working and all and the email gets sent but I just need an indication to the user that it worked.

here's the code:

validate.js:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/home",
  data: str,
  success: function(msg) {
    if (msg == 'OK') {
      this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
      this_form.find('.sent-message').slideDown();
      this_form.find("input:not(input[type=submit]), textarea").val('');
    } else {
      this_form.find('.loading').slideUp();
      this_form.find('.error-message').slideDown().html(msg);
    }
  }
})
```

index.js:

```
const express    = require("express"),
      router     = express.Router(),
      nodemailer = require("nodemailer"),
      mailGun    = require("nodemailer-mailgun-transport");

router.get("/home", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

router.post("/home", (req, res) => {
    let { firstName, lastName, email, website, company, message } = req.body;
    console.log("Data: ", req.body);

let mailOptions = {
    from: email,
    to: "myemail@email.com",
    subject: "No Subject",
    html:   "<h3>First Name: " + firstName + "</h3>" +
            "<h3>Last Name: " + lastName + "</h3>" +
            "<h3>Email: " + email + "</h3>" +
            "<h3>Company: " + company + "</h3>" +
            "<h3>Website: " + website + "</h3>" +
            "<h3>Message: " + message + "</h3>"
}

smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully sent email.")
    }
})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error says: Error Empty Response .

So why don't you just send a response ?

```
router.post("/home", (req, res) => {
    let { firstName, lastName, email, website, company, message } = req.body;
    console.log("Data: ", req.body);

let mailOptions = {
    from: email,
    to: "myemail@email.com",
    subject: "No Subject",
    html:   "<h3>First Name: " + firstName + "</h3>" +
            "<h3>Last Name: " + lastName + "</h3>" +
            "<h3>Email: " + email + "</h3>" +
            "<h3>Company: " + company + "</h3>" +
            "<h3>Website: " + website + "</h3>" +
            "<h3>Message: " + message + "</h3>"
}

smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send('false');  // <----- HERE
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully sent email.");
        res.send("OK");   // <------------- HERE
    }
})
});
```